# Unable to change paypal email on Shopify payment provider settings

Tags: paypal, shopify, integration, cart, checkout

My problem is Paypal integration with my shopify store. I lost that when I was trying to add my new Paypal email on Shopify.

On reaching Shopify support I was told to contact Paypal to resolve this. Now my customers have no option to make any payments. after clicking on "Activate Paypal Express Checkout" button on shopify payment providers page, it asked for paypal email address. I added new paypal email address which I already added on my paypal account. After that it asked to login. I logged in. Nothing changed on Shopify. the paypal checkout is not integrated on my website.

when I added my primary account for the first time, it worked. But that was my personal email. So now I created new one under my domain and added. Then I deactivated that old email which I integrated with shopify and tried to activate new one. but it is not working this change is happening on Paypal urls not Shopify. That is the reason they told me to contact you.

I have been reaching paypal support for last 4 days. I cannot afford another day wait for resolution so I'm looking for help here.

Comment: Make sure the email is confirmed in the account you want to use under https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email -- then remove PayPal completely from Shopify, and add it back.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes, I confirmed the email and deactivated the previous email and tried to add this. But it is not getting added to Shopify. That is the problem I'm facing.